# awk if or is printing unexpected result

Tags: bash, mongodb, awk

I have a shell script monitoring mongo collection records number:

```
LOWER_LIMIT=${1:-1000}
UPPER_LIMIT=${2:-4000}
xxx/bin/mongo --host myhost mydb -u username -p pwd --eval 'db.myCollection.count()'|awk -v lower=$LOWER_LIMIT -v upper=$UPPER_LIMIT '{if($1<lower || $1>upper) print $1}'
```

I am expecting null output because the actual records number is 3000, however it prints out the first column of a bunch of outputs, like mongodb connecting ...

This problem only happens if i use OR operator, && is working fine. Can anyone help point out my problem? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I guess it's because it does a non-numeric comparison, and a string that begins with a letter will be bigger (`>`) that your number, witch will match your second condition of the `or`. So you can try to fix it comparing that first field is numeric using a regular expression, like:

```
awk -v lower=$LOWER_LIMIT -v upper=$UPPER_LIMIT '
    $1 ~ /^[[:digit:]]+$/ && ($1<lower || $1>upper) { print $1 }'
```